# Toolbar in Fragments without AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I can't use Toolbar in my MainActivity 'cause it extends FragmentActivity, so i've tried to put this in my Fragment class :

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(br.com.app.coffeehour.coffee_hour.R.layout.fragment1_menu, container, false);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (mToolbar != null) {
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    }
    mToolbar.setTitle(null);

    return view;
}
```

I also tried the ActionBarActivity but it also didn't worked.

Here's the exception message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.app.coffeehour.coffeehour.app/br.com.app.coffeehour.coffee_hour.navigation.ActivityOne}: java.lang.ClassCastException: br.com.app.coffeehour.coffee_hour.navigation.ActivityOne cannot be cast to android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: br.com.app.coffeehour.coffee_hour.navigation.ActivityOne cannot be cast to android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
                  at br.com.app.coffeehour.coffee_hour.navigation.top_menu.fragment1_menu.onCreateView(fragment1_menu.java:33)
                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2442)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3273)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1334)
                  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7029)
```

Comment: `AppCompatActivity` extends `FragmentActivity` - why can't you update your Activity to extend `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: You should use `AppCompatActivity`, unless you want to directly use `Fragment` which already has an `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as the previous comments suggest, if you have only one activity it should extend AppCompatActivity or Activity (preferably AppCompatActivity because you'll have more flexibility).

If you want to use a fragment you should create a separate class
Name this class MyFragment
And now have MyFragment extend Fragment

-If you are using Android Studio, right click on your com.whateverYourAppIsCalled folder and select new Fragment >>> Fragment (Blank)

-Android Studio's Wizard will then do most of your heavy lifting and supply you with a new Fragment ready to code!

-Fragments are always attached to a parent Activity, if I am understanding correctly, you should be able to go to the onCreate() method of the Fragments parent activity and dynamically set your bar.

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            setContentView(R.layout.yourView);

mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
mToolbar.setTitle(null);
```

}

If after this the bar STILL doesn't show, then there is either an error in your toolbar XML.

--------------OR------------------

-Your toolbar needs to be inflated (Often times if you write a toolbar as opposed to using a regular actionbar it needs to be manually inflated). Inflate inside of your fragment...

```
 @Override
 public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
      }
```

--------------OR------------------

If even that fails, try checking your MANIFEST file to make sure that that particular activity's theme supports an action bar...

For instance:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MyActivityThatNeedsAToolbar"
        android:label="@string/my_Activity_That_Needs_A_Toolbar"
        android:theme="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
    </activity>

If your theme attribute says some variation of No_Action_Bar then change it to a theme that supports action bars!
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: the  setSupportActionBar(mToolbar); doesn't work : Cannot resolve method 'setSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)

And i've already done what u said, it's an activity that contains the fragment view in it:



public class fragment1_menu extends Fragment  {
    Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mToolbar = getView().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        mToolbar.setTitle(null);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

Comment: Does your toolbar have a menu? Post the xml code for your toolbar, and your toolbars menu please. I feel like the problem is with inflating the toolbar but maybe not? does it compile or are you still getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, i've found the problem. I was trying to add the toolbar in the fragments, but now i moved to the MainActivity and it's working. I didn't know that AppCompatActivity extends FragmentActivity